# Dictionary Contains key, but crashes saying it doesn't

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hey I have following code like this

```
public object RetrieveItemRun(int item)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Retrieving" + item.ToString());
    }
    return dictionary[item];
}
```

It always crashes when trying to get key of 0, the message box does show so the ContainsKey method is true, but when I try to retrieve the value from the key it crashes saying:

"The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Comment: Is this method called by multiple threads?  Honestly I just don't buy it with the code you have shown us.  Show us how you are calling `RetrieveItemRun()`, but that check is not thread safe, and another thread removing items would explain it.  Also, you're looking up `item` regardless of whether or not `Contains` returns `true`, another point of failure.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two calls to the function? Further, that return should be put into the if probably.

Comment: My guess is that you're calling this method multiple times, say for both `0` and the for `1` immediately after. The `0` call is succeeding, but the `1` is causing the error. This would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Is it possible to have inserted a null? In this case an internal NullPointerException will perhaps wrapped to a NotFoundException.

Comment: @Aubin The key is an `int` so it can't be `null`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the key independent on if it exists. Try by changing the code to:

```
   public object RetrieveItemRun(int item)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Retrieving" + item.ToString());
            return dictionary[item];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If exists, then return the item. You original code returns assuming item exits (outside check)

Comment: I understand I should have the return in the if, but the way my program works its impossible for it to have the key, even when I step through the program it clearly contains the key 0 with a value then crashes at the return line when item is clearly 0 as well. My program uses no threads its all sequential. It only does it with 0 though, when I add items to the dictionary I use dictionary.count as the key so each now value added will have keys, 0, 1, 2 ,3, etc

Comment: You should also add a `lock` for thread safety in the code of your answer.

Comment: @Kosmo How do you declare the dictionary?

Comment: @Guillaume lock is only necessary if the dictionary is written to from other threads. There is no need for lock when only reading (but it seem to be single-thread anyways according to OP).

Comment: Also for speed, use `Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ref item)`, this is a single lookup operation. Using `ContainsKey` and then accessing the value by indexer means two lookup operations.

Comment: @kosmo If indexed array is preferable consider use a List<> array instead. Then you can get item directly by its index as it's indexed automaticaly, and you won't need to any do look-up (although you can with the Contains() method).

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware If what happens in the `Dictionary` changes between the two lines according to the question, then it might worth a `lock` therefore my suggestion. But otherwise, yeah, no need.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `TryGetValue` method to avoid exception:

```
    public object RetrieveItemRun(int item)
    {
        object result;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out result))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Retrieving" + item);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is the better solution, using `TryGetValue` is faster and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 'else' would do the job for you. ContainsKey() methods throws this exception if the key is null! You better handle it also.

```
        try
        {
            if(dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Retrieving" + item.ToString());
            }            
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value not found!");
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Null key!");
            return null; 
        }
```

Comment: `ContainsKey` does not throw an exception, unless it's given `null`. So your first way will not work.